# MySQL Query idea needed

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a table, with the students of a class:

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------+
| id | nume      | prenume  | absente |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+
|  1 | Radu      | Catalina |       0 |
|  2 | Maselusa  | Andreea  |       0 |
|  3 | Goaga     | Ramona   |       0 |
|  4 | Stoica    | Teodor   |       0 |
|  5 | Petrache  | Adrian   |       0 |
|  6 | Stoica    | Dragos   |       0 |
|  7 | Florea    | Valeriu  |       0 |
|  8 | Coleasa   | Ionut    |       0 |
|  9 | Panait    | Andreea  |       0 |
| 10 | Vasile    | Codrut   |       0 |
| 11 | Ungureanu | Costin   |       0 |
| 12 | Pantazi   | Daniel   |       0 |
| 13 | Stroe     | Stefan   |       0 |
| 14 | Cojocaru  | Iulian   |       0 |
| 15 | Pirvu     | David    |       0 |
| 16 | Ion       | Raluca   |       0 |
| 17 | Olaru     | Andreea  |       0 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+
```

with id, last name, first name and absence.
Then, I have another table:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | nume_materie | medie_actuala |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | Limba romana |             0 |
|  2 | Matematica   |             0 |
|  3 | Fizica       |             0 |
|  4 | Chimie       |             0 |
|  5 | Biologie     |             0 |
|  6 | Informatica  |             0 |
|  7 | Engleza      |             0 |
|  8 | Franceza     |             0 |
|  9 | Geografie    |             0 |
| 10 | Istorie      |             0 |
| 11 | Sport        |             0 |
| 12 | Economie     |             0 |
| 13 | Psihologie   |             0 |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

With id, name of the class and actual average grade.

Now, I need to print one of those students with all classes and grades. 
Example:
I want to print this in PHP:

Radu Catalina, 0 absences.

Grades:
1. Limba Romana: 8
2. Matematica: 9
3. Fizica: 10 etc. etc. etc.

How can I do this? I have no idea.. I am a beginner. I have some idea about foreign keys and something like that, but I don't know how to use it. Please help.

Comment: Where are the grades coming from? For example an `8` in Limba Romana.

Comment: They will be controlled from the website. They can be also introduced randomly.

Comment: I think you need one more table which has `student_id`, `class_id` and `average_grade`. Then select it with using `join` to get your results.

Comment: I meant, in the tables. The grade `8` is nowhere to be found in your example.

Comment: The idea is that I wanna know how to print a person with all classes and each one with his/her grades.

Comment: The grades haven't been added yet.

Comment: Chaska, can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: Add the grades. Generating random grades is an odd idea.

Comment: this question needs more clarity. also there is tons of question like this. possible duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'natural join'.

```
//Example
SELECT  table1.*, table2.*
  FROM table1,table2
  Where table1.nume = 'Radu';
```

You can insert a foreign key either through create a table or through the alter table.

After creating a table you can use alter table.